# Cannot login to Gnome Shell after random lockup on 15.10

Tags: gnome, ati, 15.10, clutter

I installed Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 (GNOME 3.16). Things seemed fine but out of nowhere the session froze and left me no other choice but to cold reboot. After reboot, I can't login any more. I type my password, the screen goes black for a second and then returns to the login screen again.

Trying to start gnome-shell from command-line gives an error.

> (mutter:1857) Clutter - CRITICAL**. Unable to initialize Clutter:
>   Unable to open display. You have to set the display environment
>   variable, or use the --display argument.

When I specify the display with gnome-shell --display, it always returns an error `unable to open display`. I already tried a bunch of fixes after Googling, namely removing Xauthority, changing Xauthority permissions, export display, and others I can't remember, but nothing worked whatsoever. Reinstalled gnome-shell, mutter and gdm, still the same issue.

I'm using a laptop with AMD A8-7100 CPU and R7 M265 graphics with the open-source driver.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 isn't released yet (some days remain). Until then it's a development release and freezes might occur. I recommend to wait some days until it is released and check if the freeze disappears with the first updates. Then update the question. Otherwise it's likely to be closed because development versions are off-topic.

Comment: Well, since we're only a few days away, and the current development releases are frozen by now, I figured it would be cleaner to install 15.10 now than to start by 15.04 and then upgrade. I don't think much is going to change until the final release. Should I submit a bug report?

Comment: I don't know what happens during the freeze phase - something has to otherwise the release would take place immediately. Feel free to submit a bug report.